# How to create box plots for daily time series in Rstudio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, boxplot

I have daily surface runoff(mm) that starts from 01/01/1997 to 12/31/2005 (daily time step). I want to use boxplot to show surface runoff for each month for each year, and order them based on the month. For example for January, I would have 9 box plots for the month of January: 1997, 1998,..., 2005. Then February and so on...

Here is the code that I used, but it just created 12 boxplots.

```
library(ggplot2)
monthorder <- c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 
                'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
my_data$Month <- factor(format(my_data$Date, "%b"), levels = monthorder)
ggplot(my_data, aes(Month, SURQ))+ geom_boxplot()+geom_errorbar())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to handle the dates and plot layout (dodge vs scale_x vs facet), but here is one way to do it:

Generate some example data:

```
> tb = tibble(Day = seq(mdy('1/1/1997'), mdy('12/31/1999'), by = '1 week')) %>%
  mutate(SURQ = sample(0:10, n(), replace=TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(Month = month(Day, label = TRUE), Year = as.integer(year(Day)))
> tb
# A tibble: 157 x 4
# Groups:   Month, Year [36]
   Day         SURQ Month  Year
   <date>     <int> <ord> <int>
 1 1997-01-01     2 Jan    1997
 2 1997-01-08     2 Jan    1997
 3 1997-01-15     6 Jan    1997
 4 1997-01-22     0 Jan    1997
 5 1997-01-29     2 Jan    1997
 6 1997-02-05     3 Feb    1997
 7 1997-02-12     1 Feb    1997
 8 1997-02-19     1 Feb    1997
 9 1997-02-26     6 Feb    1997
10 1997-03-05     5 Mar    1997
# … with 147 more rows
```

Now plot:

```
tb %>% ggplot(aes(factor(Year), SURQ)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(vars(Month), nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnColby. I understand that at the first part you generated a sample data set.  As a beginner in R, which function should I use to split the "Date" to two columns of month and year? Instead of "tibble" that builds a Data frame.

Comment: If you already have a `tb` dataframe with `Date` column, you can just omit that first `tibble()` call and input it straight to `mutate()` to add the additional “mutated” columns `Month` and `Year`.

Comment: e.g. `tb %>% mutate(Month = ...)`. Note that `group_by()` also includes basic mutate function for convenience, which is what I did above. Try `?group_by` for more info.

Comment: Thank you @JohnColby.  But  I got an error in "month(Date, lable = TRUE)" that says :"unused argument (lable = TRUE)". Here is my code:                                                         
`my_data$Date<- as.Date(my_data$Date, "%m/%d/%Y") #factor to date
tb <- my_data

tb %>% mutate(Month = month(Date, lable = TRUE), Year = as.integer(year(Date)))
tb`

Comment: simple typo, `lable` should be `label`.

Comment: Oops!!Thanks @JohnColby.                                                                                                                Another Error for plotting: `tb %>% ggplot(aes(factor(Year), SURQ))+ geom_boxplot()+ facet_wrap(vars(Month), nrow = 1)`
 `Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `Month`.
* Plot is missing `Month`
* Layer 1 is missing `Month``